# change URIs of migrated site

Tags: htaccess, migration

Hi Ive uploaded a WP site onto a new server updated the DB and can get into the backend and even see the homepge. However, all the links are messed up.

I wasnt able to change the URL in the settings prior to moving, it was all grayed out. 
Here is the error message

```
Requested URL      http://mysite-site3.itempurl.com:80/tests/
Physical Path      h:\root\home\mysite\www\site3\tests\
```

is this where the problem is? How would I fix?

Comment: Try go to "Dashboard" -> "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and click "Save". This will regenerate links after changing the "home" and "site_url".

Comment: thanks. I tried but it didnt work

Comment: could it be the physical path is wrong?

Comment: Does site work with permalinks option "plain" (without rewrite)?

Comment: oh yes it does!

Comment: but not when I switch back to day and name

Comment: How exactly are the links "messed up"?

Answer (score 0):

Site works with "plain" permalinks.

1. Check write permission in your main wordpress dir, maybe wordpress can't write `.htaccess` file (you can upload it via FTP).
2. Check if `mod_rewrite` on server is enabled.

`mod_rewrite` status can be checked printing `phpinfo()`.
If `.htaccess` file is missing, upload a similar one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tests/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /tests/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I used `/tests/` in above code, because you wrote

> Requested URL      http://mysite-site3.itempurl.com:80/tests/
>   Physical Path      h:\root\home\mysite\www\site3\tests\

Maybe you'll have to change the path `/test/`.

Comment: oh btw this is a windows server

Comment: What web server? IIS, apache, nginx? @user718229

Comment: it is an IIS server

Comment: Did you check `<rewrite>` section in `web.config` file (located in root directory of website)? What do you have there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to replace URLs in the database (not clear from my read of your question), I've found it easiest to use a search/replace plugin to change links. I've used the [Better Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin several times, and it has worked well for me.